# how to find the highest IO consumer on a disk?

Tags: performance-tuning, io

Can some one help to find highest IO consumer on each individual disks?

i.e Which process consumes the most IO on /dev/sda, the highest IO consumer on /dev/sdb etc.

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: You mean which distro :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **iotop** command. It's top-like I/O monitor

Answer (score 1):

You can use atop. It's the top-alike tool that will show you all kind of stuff about your running processes. It will also highlight the resources that are hogged (being used heavily or becoming bottleneck for the processes).

It can also record the state of the system every X minutes, and that feature can be used as "poor man performance monitor".

To see the IO, run atop, and after it starts, press 'i' which will show you:

```
New interval in seconds (now 10):
```

Enter 1 (to see status in intervals of 1 second - which is reasonable because lower that that it becomes problem for human eye to catch all the details).

Next, press 'd' to sort processes by disk usage, and observe the system behaviour.

You can also use iotop as Maxiko sucggested, it's much simpler tool then atop, but is limited to IO monitoring only.

Comment: How to map the processes to disk?
i.e find what process is running on which disk?